# Android How do I use the same native library (.so) for multiple projects and classes?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am making a android project with some native code . running javah results in header files which contain function prototypes with fully qualified java class name in their names. I assume this means that those functions and headers are generated to be called only by the java class which was used to create them using javah.

How do I go on making a native lib that I can use with other classes as well as other projects. Like say I made a library that has a function that I want to use in all my projects then how would I build it so that I can use just the .so file each time without recompiling it for the project. I think we call this dynamic library?

Is it possible? or do I have to create seperate jni headers for each class and then reuse the remaining c/c++ code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to reuse your native library from various Java projects, you should directly bundle your native library with a Java class that is independent from your initial project.

This way you'll be able to distribute it as an Android Library Project, and use it from your various classes and projects.

Comment: Damn dude! Wonder why didn't I thought of it first :P! Great solution thanks